# Unmarshal datastore.ByteString go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Hi im trying to unmarshal  datastore entity that contain  **ByteString** field.

But i'm getting  unmarshal error, i can't figure out a way to unmarshal it 
Should i create my own [PropertyLoadSaver](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#hdr-The_PropertyLoadSaver_Interface)  ??

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type 



datastore.ByteString
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
)

type User struct {
    SubscriptionToken datastore.ByteString
}

func main() {
    u := new(User)
    str := "{\"SubscriptionToken\":\"YWR66969hjgkgkgo\"}"
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &u)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)

    }
    fmt.Println(u)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some intermediate type here. The json simply has a string, you can't directly unmarshal it into a `ByteString` without doing some custom unmarshaling implementation. Personally I would just use something like;

```
type jsonUser struct {
    SubscriptionToken string
}

type User struct {
    SubscriptionToken datastore.ByteString
}
```

Then provide a conversion method;

```
func NewUser(u jsonUser) *User {
     return &User{SubscriptionToken: StringToByteString(u.SubscriptionToken)}
}
```

So, unmarshal into the `jsonUser` type then convert it to a `User`